# Make cell act like a button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I generate a `Table` and build the cells dynamically with some content from a db. Each cell has more informations than displayed in the table. I need to make the whole cell clickable to call another function via code behind that generates a new table.

Here is a piece of code from the function that generates the `Table`:

```
TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
tCell.BackColor = (Color)converter.ConvertFromString(color_startBorderMC);
tCell.Text = Convert.ToString(row[column.ColumnName]); //fill some values into the TableCell
tCell.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "testMC"); //should call function in code behind 
tRow.Cells.Add(tCell); //add current cell to table row
```

`GetPostBackEventReference` needs a `__doPostBack` function (I think a JS function) and throws the following error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: __doPostBack is not defined

How can I make the cell clickable and call a method from code behind with arguments?

Comment: What's your TableCell library?

Comment: I'm using the normal TableCell class from Microsoft (  `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell`) @Pablo

Comment: either create a user control overload of table cell or use pure javascript client-side to catch the `onclick` event and  send it to the server. You might also want to check `Button.OnClientClick` for an example on how javascript is referenced from ASP pages

Comment: Not sure yet, but try just add the function name tCell.Attributes["onclick"] = "testMC()", and see if in your tag html the attribute is been sowing. Another thing maybe is the way that you are add the "onclick".

Comment: @Pablo that throws the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: testMC is not defined`. Looks like it is handled like an JS function. how can I call a codeBedhind method with arguments?

Comment: What about this: Attributes["onclick"]="javascript:alert('Hello! Focus lost from text box!!');"; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: that works fine @Pablo

Comment: So... if you click in the line you get the alert. Right? If so, try to change the alert to your function.

Comment: But my function is in code behind. When I write the name of my function I get the error mentioned above `... is not defined`

Comment: Right! my misunderstood, i thought that you was trying to call a javascript function. Let me think again.

Comment: I have found this article [link]http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx and it looks good. I can tell you tomorrow if it worked.

Comment: That seems to work! OK! let me know.

Comment: How can I call a JS function from CodeBehind? It worked like in the link and I can call a CodeBehind function now.